# nested description

Tags: table-of-contents

Has anyone used a nested description in LaTeX previously? For instance, if you had to group your thesis in terms of parts and chapters, and wish to provide a list in the introduction like this:

```
Part I: Review

  Chapter 2: Networks

     .
     .
Part II: Experiments

  Chapter 5: Setup

     .

     .
```

How can such a list be accomplished using LaTeX? Any suggestions?

Comment: For the love of all things holy, use `\tableofcontents` for this (or a variation thereof).  Of course, I may be wrong – I don't know exactly what the requirements are on your thesis – but I do know that nesting `description` environments isn't the answer.  Please update your question title accordingly :)

Comment: ToC falls at the beginning of the dissertation....there is an introductory chapter that sets the tone for the rest of the dissertation, wherein it is customary to list all the chapters with a brief description of their contents as well....

Comment: Grumble grumble… This could go either way, I suppose. I personally would write the little blurb (the chapter-abstract, I suppose) when I define `\section`s, etc. and then bring them back into the introduction `\tableofcontents`-style.  (This as opposed to using a nested list directly – not maintainable and not portable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some thing like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{enumitem} %% If you need to decorate
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
    \item[Part I: Review] \leavevmode   %% you need this
    \begin{description}
      \item[Chapter 1: Networks] \kant[1]
    \end{description}
    \item[Part II: Experiments] \leavevmode
    \begin{description}
      \item[Chapter 5: Setup] \kant[2]
    \end{description}
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Harish Kumar, Can you provide an example on how to actually generate the paragraph using \kant[#]? I looked up the documentation but could not figure this out.

Comment: @Vinod `\usepackage{kantlipsum}` and `\kant[1]`. You can use `1-164` as the number, for ex. `\kant[164]` is the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The following defines a command `\tocabstract` that will be printed in the table of contents, if it is toggled on. If not, the contents will be printed where it is defined (usually just after the chapter/section title).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{tocabstract}%toggle on off
\newkomafont{tocabstract}{\sffamily\small}
\toggletrue{tocabstract}
\newcommand{\tocabstract}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{tocabstract}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{4pt}}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{{\usekomafont{tocabstract}#1\par}}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{4pt}}%
}{\begin{addmargin}{1cm}%
    \usekomafont{tocabstract}%
#1%
\end{addmargin}\addvspace{\medskipamount}}%
}%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Duckburg}
\tocabstract{part of the duck universe \blindtext}
\section{Donald Duck}
\tocabstract{He is a duck. \blindtext}
\blindtext[17]
\section{Scrooge McDuck}
\tocabstract{He is a rich duck. \blindtext}
\blindtext[17]
\end{document}
```

If `\tocabstract` is toggled:

[image: vinodTocAbstractToggleOn]

If `\tocabstract` is not toggled (default), the toc has the normal appearance:
[image: vinodTocAbstractToggleOff]